# EditText loses value when scrolling ListView android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a custom `ListView` that each item of `ListView` contains two `EditTexts`.
For example when I put values for `EditText`s in first item of `ListView`, and after that I scrolling down to the end of `ListView`, I see that the last item of `ListView` is filled automatically, and also when I scrolling up, the first item loses its values.

**NOTE:** I use `TextWatcher` in this case.
What should I do for solving this problem?

**This is my adapter:**

```
public class MyResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> boardInformation = new ArrayList<>();

    EditText foodPrice;
    EditText foodName;

    Context context;
    int layoutView;

    public MyResultAdapter(Context context, int layoutView) {
        super(context, layoutView);

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutView = layoutView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View view = convertView;

        boolean convertViewWasNull = false;
        if(view == null)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layoutView, parent, false);
            convertViewWasNull = true;
        }

        foodPrice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.food_price);
        foodName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.food_name);

        if(convertViewWasNull )
        {
            //be aware that you shouldn't do this for each call on getView, just once by listItem when convertView is null
            foodPrice.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(foodPrice, position, "price"));
            foodName.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(foodName, position, "name"));
        }

        return view;
    }

    private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

        private View view;

        private int position;
        private String name;

        private GenericTextWatcher(View view, int position, String name) {
            this.view = view;
            this.position = position;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {
            updateBoardInformationArray(editable.toString());
        }


        private void updateBoardInformationArray(String newValue)
        {
            if(name.equals("name")) boardInformation.get(position).put("food_name", newValue);
            else boardInformation.get(position).put("food_price", newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, dude, I would sugget you two things, first try to work with ViewHolder Pattern and extend BaseAdapter for your Adapter. Secondly, try to avoid listView next time - use Recycler View instead, it is much much more better than listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are aware that you are reusing the views in the `ListView` using the `convertView` -- reusing the same views that go off the screen for the views that enter the screen.

> i see that the last item of listview is filled automatically

That might be because that view has been reused from another view where you have entered some text in the `EditText`.

> and also when i scrolling up, the first item loses its values.

The same reason as above. Some other view is being reused in this position.

**Solution:**

Save the user entered text in a List of some model objects. For example, like this `ArrayList<MyData>`. The `MyData` object has the typed text. And the List has one object for each item in your list.

Now in the `getView` callback get the text from the `ArrayList<MyData>` for the corresponding position and set it to the `EditText`.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day.